# Работа с проектом на удаленном/виртуальном сервере из PHPStorm и других IDE

Tags: php, ubuntu, git, ssh, phpstorm

Народ, подскажите пожалуйста как лучше и правильнее работать. Раньше всегда работал с локальным проектом и через PHPStorm фиксировал изменения в GIT и т.п. Сейчас проекты все на виртуальном сервере (Ubuntu), доступ к нему по SSH. Как правильно выстроить рабочий процесс?
Сейчас получается добавил удаленный проект по SSH и так работаю, но чтобы сделать коммит например, надо делать его через консоль и ветку не понятно как поменять тогда и т.п.

Если не понятно, могу подробнее расписать.

Comment: ниже вот предложили vscode. Хороший вариант, правда, у него есть свои особенности. Я был в похожей ситуации, и использовал vim с плагинами. А git - так у Вас есть консоль - `git branch -b new_branch` и будет создан бранч с именем new_branch и будет переключено на него. А дальше читайте документацию - в консоли можно сделать с гитом все что угодно, в отличии от UI/phpstorm

Comment: [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/remote-development/) тут недавно выпустили Gateway, через который это можно организовать, принцип которого аналогичен работе через SSH.

Comment: только не говорите, что оно требует джавы на сервере

Comment: `sshfs` - вполне себе клёвая штука.

Answer (score 1):

Правильный рабочий процесс:

1. разработка локально
2. деплой на сервер

Если по каким-то причинам хочется рабочую копию держать на удаленном сервере и нет желания изучать консольную утилиту git, то примонтируйте папку с проектом к своему компьютеру и работайте с ней как с локальной.

Comment: Да консольные команды git в целом знаю и не так сложно найти мануалы например. Но получается когда рабочая копия на удаленном сервере нельзя нормально поменять ветку и так же увидеть нормально разницу в измененных файлах например, как наглядно это видно в IDE. Как лучше примонтировать папку с проектом из Ubuntu, может сталкивались?

Comment: например Network File System https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/nfs

Comment: @ramiscoder https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) для удаленной разработки. Чтобы настроить редактор кода вам нужен плагин [remote SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh). VS code после подключений с сервером будет работать на сервере, соответсвенно, от имени сервера можете выполнять всё.

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант:

1. Разработка ведётся локально.
2. В настройках проекта указано, чтобы локальные файлы при сохранении автоматически синхронизировались с вашим рабочим каталогом на удалённом сервере по SSH.
3. Изменения фиксируются в локальной копии GIT и по необходимости пушатся.
4. В боевом каталоге тоже есть копия GIT. По необходимости в консоли просто вызывается git pull.

Преимущества: пользуемся всеми возможностями, предоставляемыми средой разработки.
Недостатки: при переключении веток необходимо дождаться, пока изменения синхронизируются.